# MySQL Server 5.7 installation fails at "Writing configuration file"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL Server 5.7.7 on Windows Server 2008 machine. It has failed several times and I tried uninstalling the whole thing and try the installation again. I tried installing one component at a time and it worked for all the components (Workbench, connectors,..etc.) except for the MySQL Server itself.

I'm receiving error at the step "Writing configuration file", the log shows the error details below:

```
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini'.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i had the same problem. to solve it, i simply created the "MySQL Server 5.7" folder in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL" then clicked Retry in the installer

i've had bad experiences with MySQL installers in the past. really surprised it's not smart enough (or too lazy?) to create the sub folders before trying to write the ini file.

hope that helps!

Comment: In the last version you have to create a `MySQL Server 5.7` folder inside `C:\ProgramData\MySQL` it just sucks that MySQL installer can't do that. :(

Comment: thanks Rafael! forgot the "Server" portion of the folder name!