# MySQL Server 5.7.7 installation stuck on "Starting Server" on Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1

I downloaded the mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.24.0.msi from [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/).
First I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866381/mysql-server-5-7-installation-fails-at-writing-configuration-file) issue which was resolved. Then I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server) issue and while applying the suggested fix I am getting the following error

[image]

and the installer is still stuck on "Starting Server" with the following message

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues feel like deja-vu for me. I'm using the same MySQL installer on **Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit**. I had the `my.ini` issue and resolved it the same way. Next up to bat was the service not starting.

After checking the  service Properties, it didn't take long to notice that the `<MySQLinstallPath>\bin` directory wasn't created. I created it manually, cancelled then killed the installer (all the way out). Ran the '*MySQL Installer - Community*' from the menu as administrator and removed everything the installer put on my disk. So it really didn't make a difference creating the `bin` directory, save yourself the time and skip it.

Then I removed the '*MySQL Installer - Community*' from Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program. You can choose to reboot, but I was in the middle of something and choose not to. Not rebooting didn't seem to make a noticeable difference. I suppose it depends upon the Windows OS version you are installing on.

Moving along, find the '`mysql-installer-community-5.6.24.0`' you previously downloaded, R-click and select 'Install'. Follow the prompts, until it asks you the type of install you want. I selected '*Server Only*'. Follow the installer instructions and hopefully you too will have SUCCESS!

I still haven't rebooted.

-Heal

No security, no privacy. Know security, know privacy.

Comment: I had MySQL Workbench installed before, uninstalling that and then installing MySQL Server first and later MySQL Workbench did the trick.
-Cheers

Comment: I spent two days trying to get MySQL community edition installed on my Windows 2012R2 server trying all solutions I found but still got the "...taking too long to start" error. Since there was no requirement to install MySQL I went for MariaDB and that installed at once with no hassle at all.